# Limit X axis due to direct drive

Tags: creality-ender-3, direct-drive

Recently I printed [this direct drive mod](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3816051) and installed into my Ender 3.

After installation, the stepper motor constantly bangs into the right Z frame of the printer. I have already set the bed X axis size to 190 mm within Cura slicer and my OctoPi printer profile but when homing, it will home to left and move towards right at a fairly fast speed and "BANG", I can hear the motor skipping a few steps, not sure how to proceed from here...

Comment: What flavor and version of firmware are you running?

Comment: A photo would be welcome also! It homes in the correct direction, I'm curious why it moves instantly to the right, a link to a video might be interesting to.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a pancake stepper I heard those work quite well, they do have less torque but you can overcome that with gear ratio's like on the bondtech extruders. It should be thin enough so you can use the full volume again. If you dont think that's worth it you should move you X-axis endstop since the homing is where it goes wrong, as far as firmware goes I can't help you in that aspect as well as other would be able too. I hope this helps.